# Installing another OS without USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I recently wanted to install (most probably dual-boot) Windows 7 in my laptop. I downloaded the .iso file for Windows 7, when I found out that I had no USB drives. So, I made a NTFS partition in my Drive (/dev/sda3), and extracted all the files there, hoping to boot the Windows 7 Setup from that partition.

I also made changes to the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file to add the option for the currently extracted drive to show up in boot.

Added the following code in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-724D5FE1694E60F9' {
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    
    
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  724D5FE1694E60F9
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 724D5FE1694E60F9
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

(Some changes were automatically made after running `update-grub`)

I also set the ***boot*** flag in the partition.

But after doing all these things, it didn't seem to work.
During boot, an error shows up saying:

```
This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floppy and press any key to try again...
```

Is there any possible fix for this problem?

Is it possible to make a bootable hard disk without using a USB?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there's no master boot record in a partition , you cannot boot it. You have to first extract the ISO file to that partition.Then try again.The ISO file should contain the desired boot record.

Comment: Forgot to mention , you have to extract it via **dd** not via some archive manager.You can do this : ```sudo dd if=/iso/file/address of=/dev/sda3 status=progress```. That will erase the NTFS partition on your ```/dev/sda3``` but make it bootable. After installing your windows , you can re-format that partition to NTFS again.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to dual boot, you should install Windows first. The Linux Grub2 bootloader can handle a pre-existing Windows installation, but the last time I tried it, the Windows installer will wipe out your Linux boot. It is not worth the trouble.

Comment: I think it's possible to bring up the grub after windows installation. You just have to run ```update-grub``` in a live ISO or even in your current linux installation. You have to bring up the boot menu of your system and boot into **ubuntu** , then you can run ```update-grub```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what exactly happened, but I was simply entering some random, but valid commands in the ***grub-cli***.

The usual things I would try are:

- Making the partition with the files (in this case `/dev/sda3`) as root:

`set root=(hd0,msdos3)`

- Inserting some necessary modules:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
```

- Loading the `bootmgr` file (which I later came to know, is the Kernel):

```
ntldr /bootmgr
```

That was the part where I got stuck. But this time I tried some really random commands (which might be invalid too). But, one command really worked and directly booted to the Windows 7 Setup:

```
boot
```

Everything worked fine, so I restarted my laptop, and tried the same set of commands:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos3)
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
ntldr /bootmgr
boot
```

And it worked again. So, I changed the grub configuration file (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) as such (it was literally just adding two lines to the original code):

```
menuentry 'Windows 7' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-724D5FE1694E60F9' {
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  724D5FE1694E60F9
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 724D5FE1694E60F9
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    ntldr /bootmgr
    boot
    chainloader +1
}
```

After successfully saving these changes (as `sudo`), the **Windows 7** option in the boot window started working.

Thanks to everyone who put there time figuring out the solution.

**Note.** There are different solutions to the same problem. For me this solution worked great, if it doesn't work for you, try all the solutions mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no boot record in a partition , you cannot boot it. You have to first extract the ISO file to that partition.Then try again.The ISO file should contain the desired boot record(as is the case for installation ISOs).

First off you have to extract it via **dd** , not a normal archive manager , because it have to rewrite the [Partition Boot Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record) of the desired partition. So run this ( I do this each time I want to create a bootable USB stick) :

```
sudo dd if=/iso/file/address of=/dev/sda3 status=progress
```

Note that this will remove your NTFS partition so make sure you don't have any special file or data in that partition.Then I don't think there would be any problem booting the partition.If you cannot boot it via **grub2** , try your system boot menu(Usually it's <kbd>F12</kbd> but might differ based on your motherboard).

After the installation has finished, you can reformat that partition to **NTFS** again.

But if you cannot boot your linux after installation because the **Windows** bootloader has taken the precedence over **grub2** as @summertime said , you can boot the **ubuntu** via the aforementioned method (i.e system boot menu) , then just run :

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Master Boot Record is not a property of the partition but of the drive, so just using dd on a partition will not set it. You'd need to rewrite the entire drive.

Comment: @user1937198 Yes , you're right. I did a tiny mistake there.I had to use **Volume boot record** or **Partition Boot record** not **Master Boot Record** which is the property of the whole drive not a partition. Thanks for pointing out. Updated.